# How to use extension functions defined in Kotlin interface

Tags: kotlin, interface

In Kotlin, it is possible to declare an extension function in an interface like this:

```
interface Evaluator {
  fun Double.evaluateY1(): Double
  fun Double.evaluateY2(): Double
}

class EvaluatorImpl : Evaluator {
    override fun Double.evaluateY1(): Double {
        return this + 2.0
    }

    override fun Double.evaluateY2(): Double {
        return this + 3.0
    }
}
```

Having a receiver and an instance of the interface, how do I invoke such extension function?

I came up with a trick involving the `with` scope function, but I would prefer something with less indentation.

```
fun usageExample(evaluator: Evaluator, x: Double) {
  with(evaluator) {
    println("Y1 = ${x.evaluateY1()}. Y2 = ${x.evaluateY2()}")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no chance to make it work without getting into the scope of your interface. Using `with` is the recommended solution. You can use an expression body to make it more concise:

```
fun usageExample(evaluator: Evaluator, x: Double) = with(evaluator) {
    println("Y1 = ${x.evaluateY1()}. Y2 = ${x.evaluateY2()}")
}
```